# How to calculate the conditional expectation Weibull model?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, weibull

I would like to calculate the conditional expectation of the Weibull model. In specific, I would like to estimate the remaining tenure of a client looking at random moments (time = t) in his total tenure.

To do so, I have calculated the total tenure for each client (currently active or inactive) and based on the random moment for each client, calculated his/her tenure at that moment.

The example below is a snapshot of my attempt. I use 2 variables *STED* and *TemporalTenure* to predict the dependent variable *tenure* which has either status 0 = active or 1 = inactive. I use the `survival` package for obtaining the survival object (km_surv).

```
df = structure(list(ID = c(16008, 21736, 18851, 20387, 30749, 
42159), STED = c(2, 
5, 1, 3, 2, 2), TemporalTenure = c(84, 98, 255, 392, 108, 278
), tenure = c(152, 166, 273, 460, 160, 289), status = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
    
        
km_surv <- Surv(time = df$tenure, event = df$status)
df <- data.frame(y = km_surv, df[,!(names(df) %in% c("tenure","status", "ID"))])
weibull_fit <- psm(y ~. , dist="weibull", data = df)

quantsurv <- Quantile(weibull_fit, df)
lp <- predict(weibull_fit, df, type="lp") 
print(quantsurv(0.5, lp))
```

The output of these estimations are way too high. I assume this is caused by including the *TemporalTenure*, but I can't find out how the `psm` package calculates this and if there are other packages where it's possible to estimate the remaining tenure of client i at time t.

How can I obtain the predicted tenure conditioned over the time that a client is already active (random moment in time: TemporalTenure) where the dependent tenure can either be a client that is still active or one that is inactive?

**EDIT**

To clarify, whenever I add time conditional variables such as: TemporalTenure, number of received payments and number of complaints until time t, the predicted lifetime explodes in many cases. Therefore, I suspect that the `psm` is not the right way to go. Similar question is asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/conditional-expected-lifetime-in-survival-analysis), but the solution given doesn't work for the same reasons.

Below a slightly bigger dataset which already causes problems.

```
df = structure(list(ID= c(16008, 21736, 18851, 20387, 30749, 
                         42159, 34108, 47511, 47917, 61116, 66600, 131380, 112668, 90799, 
                         113615, 147562, 166247, 191603, 169698, 1020841, 1004077, 1026953, 
                         1125673, 1129788, 22457, 1147883, 1163870, 1220268, 2004623, 
                         1233924, 2009026, 2026688, 2031284, 2042982, 2046137, 2043214, 
                         2033631, 2034252, 2068467, 2070284, 2070697, 2084859, 2090567, 
                         2087133, 2087685, 2095100, 2095720, 2100482, 2105150, 2109353, 
                         28852, 29040, 29592, 29191, 31172, 2126369, 2114207, 2111947, 
                         2102678, 237687, 1093221, 2111607, 2031732, 2105275, 2020226, 
                         1146777, 1028487, 1030165, 1098033, 1142093, 1186763, 2005605, 
                         2007182, 2021092, 2027676, 2027525, 2070471, 2070621, 2072706, 
                         2081862, 2085084, 2085353, 2094429, 2096216, 2109774, 2114526, 
                         2115510, 2117329, 2122045, 2119764, 2122522, 2123080, 2128547, 
                         2130005, 30025, 24166, 61529, 94568, 70809, 159214), STED = c(2, 
                                                                                       5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 
                                                                                       1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 
                                                                                       2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 
                                                                                       3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
                                                                                       3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1), TemporalTenure = c(84, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         98, 255, 392, 108, 278, 120, 67, 209, 95, 224, 198, 204, 216, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         204, 190, 36, 160, 184, 95, 140, 256, 142, 216, 56, 79, 194, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         172, 155, 158, 78, 24, 140, 87, 134, 111, 15, 126, 41, 116, 66, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         60, 0, 118, 22, 116, 110, 52, 66, 0, 325, 323, 53, 191, 60, 7, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         45, 73, 42, 161, 30, 17, 30, 12, 87, 85, 251, 120, 7, 6, 38, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         119, 156, 54, 11, 141, 50, 25, 33, 3, 48, 58, 13, 113, 25, 18, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         23, 2, 102, 5, 90, 0, 101, 83, 44, 125, 226, 213, 216, 186), 
           tenure = c(152, 166, 273, 460, 160, 289, 188, 72, 233, 163, 
                      266, 266, 216, 232, 247, 258, 65, 228, 252, 99, 208, 324, 
                      201, 284, 124, 84, 262, 180, 223, 226, 146, 92, 208, 155, 
                      202, 179, 80, 185, 64, 184, 120, 65, 6, 186, 45, 120, 170, 
                      96, 123, 12, 393, 391, 64, 259, 73, 42, 69, 141, 47, 229, 
                      37, 19, 37, 17, 155, 99, 319, 188, 75, 11, 49, 187, 180, 
                      55, 52, 209, 115, 93, 88, 6, 53, 126, 31, 123, 26, 26, 24, 
                      9, 114, 6, 111, 4, 168, 84, 112, 193, 294, 278, 284, 210), 
           status = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                       0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                       1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), TotalValue = c(2579.35, 2472.85, 
                                                                  581.19, 2579.35, 2472.85, 0, 1829.18, 0, 936.79, 2098.2, 
                                                                  850.47, 2579.35, 463.68, 463.68, 2171.31, 3043.03, 561.16, 
                                                                  3043.03, 3043.03, -68.06, 2098.2, 2504.4, 1536.67, 2719.7, 
                                                                  3043.03, 109.91, 2579.35, 265.57, 3560.34, 2266.95, 3123.16, 
                                                                  3544.4, 1379.19, 2288.35, 2472.85, 2560.48, 1414.45, 3741.49, 
                                                                  202.2, 2856.23, 1457.75, 313.68, 191.32, 2266.95, 661.01, 
                                                                  0, 2050.81, 298.76, 1605.44, 373.86, 3043.03, 2579.35, 448.63, 
                                                                  3043.03, 463.68, 977.28, 818.06, 2620.06, 0, 3235.8, 280.99, 
                                                                  0, 0, 194.04, 3212.75, -23.22, 1833.46, 1829.18, 2786.7, 
                                                                  0, 0, 3250.38, 936.79, 0, 1045.21, 3043.03, 1988.36, 2472.85, 
                                                                  1197.94, 0, 313.68, 3212.75, 1419.33, 531.14, 0, 96.28, 0, 
                                                                  142.92, 174.79, 0, 936.79, 156.19, 2472.85, 463.68, 3520.69, 
                                                                  2579.35, 3328.87, 2567.88, 3043.03, 1081.14)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                               100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So the bounty was just a tease and you never planned to honor the offer? Doesn't matter that much to me but it may affect how people assess your reputation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hoping there would be still a different solution since yours doesn't change the result on my complete dataset. I have to agree, I was surprised that there is a different result with your solution, but I still get very high tenures when I run it on the complete dataset. Therefore, it feels like the psm solution is not made for conditional tenures.

Comment: The cause of the crazy estimates was including the ID column in the covariates. (And you have not corrected that probable error in the code above.)There were several other infelicities that I demonstrated better practices to follow. Without a clear understanding of what you are seeing with your "complete dataset", I don't see how further effort is going to be fruitful.

Comment: My apologies. I have now posted the first 100 rows in the edit with one extra variable "TotalValue". If I run your solution I get a result of 4500 in one case. This is approximately 10 times bigger than the maximum actual tenure. When I add more variables like this, these tenures become even more out of the ordinary.

Comment: The `psm` function constructs a parametric function with potentially very long tails. It's quite possible that it will predict very long times. I also  think there's a potential problem predicting `tenure` from a predictor named `TemporalTenure`. Among the status==0 group there's almost a perfect straight line fit in the data you offered.

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I have done: 1) added library call to load pkg:rms, removed the attempt to place a `Surv` object in a dataframe column, 3) built the `Surv` object inside formula as Therneau expects formulas to be built, and removed ID from the covariates where it most probably does not belong.

```
library(survival); library(rms)

#km_surv <- Surv(time = df$tenure, event = df$status)
#df <- data.frame(y = km_surv, df[,!(names(df) %in% c("tenure","status"))])
weibull_fit <- psm(Surv(time = tenure, event = status) ~TemporalTenure +STED , dist="weibull", data = df)

quantsurv <- Quantile(weibull_fit, df)
lp <- predict(weibull_fit, df, type="lp")
```

Results#

```
print(quantsurv(0.5, lp))
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
151.4129 176.0490 268.4644 466.8266 164.8640 301.2630
```